# Forefront 2010 (TMG): infinite redirection loop

Tags: isa-server, microsoft-forefront, microsoft-forefront-2010, tmg

The behaviour of the internal web server is to detect an incoming request over HTTP and respond with a 301 response to a HTTPS location (for all or only specific URLs), then TMG interferes and the HTTP Location header that is returned to the original client does not include the HTTPS scheme and the client’s browser.

Eg. on client request:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
```

the response from my web server is:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://www.example.com/index.html
```

but the response from Forefront (see http instead of https)

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.example.com/index.html
```

How can i fix this behaviour?

**UPDATE**

I have foud the solution https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/924373/link-translation-causes-an-endless-loop-when-you-use-web-servers-that